# Visual Studio not installed error

Tags: visual-studio

I know this is not exactly a programming question but I don't even know how to google it so here I am.
I currently have Visual Studio 2013 Express and I get the error above when am trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects extension, what is missing? Any help will be highly appreciated.

[[image: 1]]

Comment: Express editions do not support extensions. That's a very well known limitation, the main difference from the Professional editions. Why are you using 2013 at all though? VS 2015 Community is equivalent to Professional, which means it supports the same extensions and plugins

Comment: Got that, switching to Professional @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects), this requires Visual Studio 2013.

Visual Studio 2013 Express is **not** Visual Studio 2013 (meaning paid version). Or at least, only a subset, with a different product ID.

You'll have to use the paid version of VS or choose another setup method.

Comment: Seriously!! Okay let me install another version and try it all over again

Comment: @lulliezy why are you installing an *old* version when you can install the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition which *does* support extensions? Anyway, the lack of extensions support in VS Express is a very well known limitation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am currently on Windows 8.1 and I tried installing VS 2015 but couldn't, compatibility issues so I resorted to VS 2013, but right now am switching to VS Professional hoping it will work

Comment: What compatibility issues? VS 2015 isn't broken. It doesn't require Windows 10 or 7. You should fix whatever issues your machine has then install it, not get stuck 2 versions behind the current VS and 1 version behind the current C# language

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I am installing VS 2015 now and after installing VS 2013 Professional, the extension installed successfully